# How can i show or hide certain divs on my UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

on Success=True i want to show the div with bg-success?
on Success=False i want to show the div with bg-danger?

```js
success: function(data) {
  if (data.Success == true) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('div.bg-success').removeClass('hide');

  }
  if (data.Success == false) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('div.bg-danger').show();

  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>Name 1</td>
  <td>
    <input class="text-box single-line nameReservation1" id="NameSet_0_" name="NameSet[0]" type="text" value="" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="bg-success hide">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle "> Potentially available</span>

    </div>
    <div class="bg-danger hide">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign red"> Not  available</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There's no question here. Do you have an issue with the code?

Comment: Try `$(this).parents("td:first").find('div.bg-success').removeClass('hide');` Either you use `show()` `hide()` or use `addClass()` `removeClass()`. Don't do mixup.

Comment: Yes Rory, i am having an issue displaying Potentially available if my Success value is True

Comment: try using the same code as u r using to show the bg-danger

Comment: it still doesnt show

Comment: $(this).parents("td:first").find('div.bg-danger').removeClass('hide')

Comment: I havent found a  working solution yet

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your question, you just want to show/hide divs.

Use the [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property to either show (display:inline) or hide (display:none) specific divs.